# Calculate RSI with postgresql based on language C function from tulip indicator

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, function

Is it possible to implement RSI function in the database? https://github.com/TulipCharts/tulipindicators 
I have market data inside postgresql table and I would like to calculate RSI on this data. Can we use the code written in language "C"

```
#include "../indicators.h" 
int ti_rsi_start(TI_REAL const *options) {
return (int)options[0];
}
int ti_rsi(int size, TI_REAL const *const *inputs, TI_REAL const *options, TI_REAL *const *outputs) {
const TI_REAL *input = inputs[0];
const int period = (int)options[0];
TI_REAL *output = outputs[0];
const TI_REAL per = 1.0 / ((TI_REAL)period);

if (period < 1) return TI_INVALID_OPTION;
if (size <= ti_rsi_start(options)) return TI_OKAY;

TI_REAL smooth_up = 0, smooth_down = 0;

int i;
for (i = 1; i <= period; ++i) {
    const TI_REAL upward = input[i] > input[i-1] ? input[i] - input[i-1] : 0;
    const TI_REAL downward = input[i] < input[i-1] ? input[i-1] - input[i] : 0;
    smooth_up += upward;
    smooth_down += downward;
}

smooth_up /= period;
smooth_down /= period;
*output++ = 100.0 * (smooth_up / (smooth_up + smooth_down));

for (i = period+1; i < size; ++i) {
    const TI_REAL upward = input[i] > input[i-1] ? input[i] - input[i-1] : 0;
    const TI_REAL downward = input[i] < input[i-1] ? input[i-1] - input[i] : 0;

    smooth_up = (upward-smooth_up) * per + smooth_up;
    smooth_down = (downward-smooth_down) * per + smooth_down;

    *output++ = 100.0 * (smooth_up / (smooth_up + smooth_down));
}

assert(output - outputs[0] == size - ti_rsi_start(options));
return TI_OKAY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly put this code into a C function, but you'd have to modify the function so that it can be used with PostgreSQL.

Most notably, you have to add the *magic block* and you have to declare the function and pass arguments and the return value according to the [*Version 1 Calling Conventions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#idm46428687639680).